# HttpSessionStorage - Message not found in SESSION

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I was able to integrate **Single Sign-On** using **Spring Security SAML** into my web app. But I'm having issues when adding this dependency `org.springframework.session`.

First it stores data to the session, then redirect to IDP.

```
DEBUG o.s.s.s.storage.HttpSessionStorage - Storing message a4850861j4f289ha850h8gh92hj85d to session c5a13884-37d5-4e3d-b5ec-44ac6013de7a
```

After successful authentication, it cannot found the stored data from the SESSION as it's id changes.

```
DEBUG o.s.s.s.storage.HttpSessionStorage - Message a4850861j4f289ha850h8gh92hj85d not found in session 6c84d9a8-2c78-4e3b-8726-4f8129e9a543
DEBUG o.s.s.s.SAMLAuthenticationProvider - Error validating SAML message
org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message a4850861j4f289ha850h8gh92hj85d
```

The creation of SESSION name `"mujinaSpSessionId"` gets overwritten when the dependency is added.

```
@Bean
  public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
    //otherwise the two localhost instances override each other session
    return servletContext -> {
      SessionCookieConfig sessionCookieConfig = servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig();
      sessionCookieConfig.setName("mujinaSpSessionId");
      sessionCookieConfig.setSecure(this.secureCookie);
      sessionCookieConfig.setHttpOnly(true);
    };
  }
```

For reference I'm following an implementation from **Mujina** and here's the link to the code [**WebSecurityConfigurer.java**](https://github.com/OpenConext/Mujina/blob/master/mujina-sp/src/main/java/mujina/sp/WebSecurityConfigurer.java).

Any answer will help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after searching some answers, I've found an answer from this question
[Spring SAML sending wrong AuthNRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65701312/7663474)

The main issue comes from the `SAMLContextProviderLB` it's having conflicts with Spring Session.

This line of code worked for me.

```
samlContextProviderLB.setStorageFactory(new EmptyStorageFactory());
```